# How to replace the content of a flow file that exists between [ and ]?

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to remove the entire content between the brackets of a flow file attribute. Attached is my sample Flow file and in which I wanted to remove the content between [ and ]. May I know the search and replacement value to be used from ReplaceText Processor ?

[Flow File content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgOKf.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can put following regular expression in the 'Search value' filed to detect all the content between brackets. This will select the whole text including the brackets.

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

If you put an empty string in the 'Replacement value', it will clear all the content between brackets (including the brackets itself). If you would like to keep the brackets in the output use `[]` as the 'Replacement value'.

Comment: Hi Snajaya, Thanks for your input. It really worked. Thank you.

Comment: @SPK Hi,
Glad it helped you. Please mark the answer as the correct answer so that other users will be able to find the correct answer easily.